# Ruby project practice (non-rails)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I usually develop rails applications.
But sometimes, I make non-rails ruby scripts - for example, text converter, web crawler, etc.
When it's non-rails, the program consists of one or several ruby files in a single directory.
I don't think that's a good practice.
So I searched for best practice for ruby projects.

All I found was about how to make gems.
I am kinda confused.
When I work on a ruby project, do I make a gem first and use it?
Then, where is the gem-calling script located? (I guess /bin?)

Gem is about reusing codes, right?
What about throw-away script?

How do you do this?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: I found a very useful doc at http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to package a gem if you want to distribute a piece of software either publicly (on http://rubygems.org) or within a private organisation (running [your own Gem server](http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/)). However, if you are building something for your own use only, you can just use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to manage your project's dependencies. I generally find this easier than maintaining a gem, as it dispenses you from the need of continuously updating the `.gemspec` manifest, and having to care about potentially irrelevant details such as release numbers, files and folders included in the gem package, etc..

Answer (score 2):

> When I work on a ruby project, do I make a gem first and use it?

Sure, you can if you want.  A gem is just a way to say "This project has these dependencies.  If they are not present, things will fail to work."  Including a gem just makes it easier to ship your code around and get predictable results using external ruby files.

> Then, where is the gem-calling script located?

To find out where the gem-calling script is located, check out:

```
$ which gem
```

via your command line.